# How do could I use VBA RegExp (or other function) in Excel to escape special characters?

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I need to be able to look through several ranges and add a "\" before any of these characters #$%&_{}~\^ that are not already preceeded by a "\".  Can anybody help?  I've been fooling around with this for a couple of hours and I know it should be simple to somebody who is more familiar with regular expressions.  If there is another simple way, that's fine too.

Below is my lame attempt at making this work.  I think that I need to include back references, but that is confounding me.

```
Function EC(code As Range)


    Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "[^\\]+[#$%^&_{}\~]"
    Dim strReplace As String: strReplace = "[\]+[#$%^&_{}\~]"
    Dim myreplace As Long
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim Myrange As Range

    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    For Each cell In code
        If strPattern <> "" Then
            strInput = cell.Value

            With RegEx
                .Global = True
                .MultiLine = True
                .IgnoreCase = False
                .Pattern = strPattern
            End With
            If RegEx.Test(strInput) Then
                 EC = (RegEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace))
            Else: EC = code.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Set RegEx = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Always best to show what you already tried, so folks can get a quicker start on helping you find a solution.  See [ask]

Comment: what about formulas which have them? `C:\Sample.xlsx` will end up as `C:\\Sample.xlsx`  and `=2^3` will become `=2\^3` and so on...

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=regular+expression+find+and+replace

Comment: do a search and replace on the relevant ranges ( https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+excel+replace )